# FontForge Gylph name

Tags: fonts, glyph, fontforge

Hi using font forge in windows when i load the font file it creates glyph name for each glyph in font file. My area of interest is how this name are generated in fontforge?

Answer (score 2):

By default, FontForge uses the [Adobe Glyph List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Glyph_List) as its name list, which provides glyph names like *ydieresis*; these are the names used within FontForge .sfd files. FontForge also displays Unicode names such as *LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS*.

If you like, you can [change the namelist](https://fontforge.github.io/encodingmenu.html#namelist) for a given font.

Answer (score 0):

These names are decided by the Unicode consortium.

https://github.com/fontforge/libuninameslist is a C library that FontForge uses to look the information up.

Answer (score 0):

Most unicode character has a unique name.
See: http://unicode.org/charts/charindex.html